# Aws RDS Connected via MySQLl Workbench but not Visual Studio

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, visual-studio-2015, amazon-rds

I have an AWS RDS instance which I'm successfully connecting to via MySQL Workbench. However, I cannot connect to the RDS in Visual Studio (via connection string in Web.config) using the same credentials. Here, the connection times-out when I run `update-database` and gives: `Error Number:53,State:0,Class:20`, and `error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server`.

My connection string is in the following format:

```
<add name="ConnectionName" connectionString="Data Source=[NAME].[REGION].rds.amazonaws.com; database=[DB_NAME]; user=[USERNAME]; password=[PASSWORD]; Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Is there any issue with this connection string, or could I be missing something else entirely?

I don't have access to AWS Workbench, so I can't check any of the RDS settings, as the database was setup for me.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Data.SQLClient` expects the other end to be a Microsoft SQL Server database, not a MySQL database. Instead you'll need to download and install a MySQL Managed Data provider and configure that as your provider:

See:

- https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/5.0.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html

Simplest way to get the MySQL Client distributed with your application is probably to [use the NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/).

Example:

```
 <add name="MySqlConnectionString" 
      connectionString="server=127.0.0.1;User Id=root;password=bpdash;database=sample"
      providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```